# jQuery get height of viewport size but -(n)px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry if the subject is confusing couldn't know how to explain better, 
so i use jQuery to set a div height to match viewport size

```
var slidevh = function() {
    var bheight = $(window).height();
    $(".container").css('height', bheight);
};
$(document).ready(slidevh);
$(window).resize(slidevh);
```

Now this works fine,  But I want the height to become - 100 pixels of the viewport size,
for example if the height was 500px I want the size to become 400px :)

is there any better way to do this? maybe pure css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css `calc` mixin

```
.container {
   height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

in javascript jquery

```
var slidevh = function() {
    var bheight = $(window).height();
    $(".container").css('height', bheight - 100);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)